# Android emulator (Genymotion) and proxyfier

Tags: android, proxy, fiddler, genymotion

The question is if it is possible instead of IP as targets get domains like standard browsers and other windows software provide.

When we use any android emulator. For example Genymotion.

[Standard applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2NfE.png)

[Android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKmku.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Comment: Actually question doesnt require any code. It is related to any android emulator and any proxyfire software